# Subtracting multiple rasters one point values from each related raster

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, modelbuilder, raster-calculator, value-extraction

I must extract values by point (just one point) from multiple "Tif" format raster and then times these values to -1 and add  them to the raster files with raster calculator (calibration).
I did as what you can see in image to have shapefile for each raster with field raster value(extract by just one point)in one row.

Can you help me for the calculate procedure part?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can anybody help me for the calculate procedure part with correcting syntax of this "disp_2017179.tif"-"disp_2017179.shp_rastervalue" to use in rastercalculator

Comment: or something like this:  ("disp_2017179.tif")-Lookup("disp_2017179.shp","rastervalue")

Comment: maybe i should convert point value shape file to raster (point to raster)  then using raster calculator